# php server-side script variable memory

Tags: php

I have a game that I have been working on.
I use php and mssql for the server side script.
Every time the user communicates with the server(URL Variables) it will make many mssql querys and do some math .
What I would like to achieve is that the server will remember the values of the querys and math between communications.
I believe this would reduce stress on the server.
I've considered savings all the data as session variables but I've read that to be a horrible idea. I did try this but I scrapped and rewrote the script.

I would try writing the variables to a text file(.php) then having that file included when the script runs .... however my server doesn't grant me file permission.

Does anyone have thoughts on this?
Should I use something other than php?

Comment: What do you mean by `however my server doesn't grant me file permission`?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to reinvent caching

Comment: Is the server stressed? Is this a problem that you need to use time on fixing?